# got an issue when updated to Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode

When I updated to Xcode 7.3,I cannot run my app on my iPhone devices (as shown below), but it works on simulators, don't know why. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: did you try to clean and build the project again? or there may be issue related to signing as you are trying for device, please try on simulator also

Comment: Whats your ios version on device ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the settings have been misconfigured. To resolve this issue, Please try the following steps.

**Check your bundle identifier in your project and your developer account. They must be the same.**

If this doesn't resolve your problem then please do the following step.

Select "**Preference"** tab of XCode and then Select "**Accounts**". Now add your apple id credentials and do login.

After Login, you'll see "**View Details**" buttons. Click on the button and it'll show **all provisioning profile** associated with your account. Click on "**Download All**" button. This will download all the profiles from apple developer account.

Also, under build settings of your XCode project, Choose **Code Signing identity** to '**iOS Developer'** and provisioning profile to '**Automatic**'.

If above both steps are not able to solve issue, then create a new certificate with **Keychain access** and **update your provisioning profile with this certificate**. Now, Follow the previous step and this will surely solve your issue.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: It not works for me... right now I already spend a week to find out the reason,but got nothing.  I can archive project, but i can't  run it on my device,my other apps works on my device.so I don't know why

Answer (score -1):

Delete the your project's derived data.